# Alfresco workflow create user task dinamically

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I have a custom workflow in Alfresco 5.2 community. I have a parallel user task assigned to a activiti:collection="mywf_reviewersAssignees", and that variable is chosen at the beginning of the workflow. All works fine.

Now, under some circumstances, while the reviewers are completing their task, I need to add another user to that collection, so that another user task is created.
I have managed to handle the "when" correctly, but I do not know how to create/add a user task.

In other words I need to "reassign" the task, extending the default Alfresco behavior. Instead of changing the task owner I need to close the previous user task and create a new one to the new user.

Is this possibile?, thanks

**EDIT**

I've read this link ([How to assign Workflow to the new user of the group?](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-process-services/how-to-assign-workflow-to-the-new-user-of-the-group/td-p/186208)) which suggest to use the candidateUsers variable, **but** I need all of the users complete their work, I can't have them as candidate and let only one to do their work

A similar question is asked here [Create User Multi Instance Task Programatically](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-process-services/create-user-multi-instance-task-programatically/m-p/82502), but unfortunately none answered

Comment: have you considered greg's response on the community thread? during the execution of the multi instance task you can add more tasks just by adding more values to the input collection

Comment: Well, I do use a collection, and like Greg answered to that post: "But in my use case, when there is still opened tasks instances, I may need to add another ones, programatically, based on runtime conditions that does not exists in the moment on the flow execution that creates the firts tasks. Is it even possible?I"

ll do another test, just to be sure I did not done it wrong the first time

Comment: one thing i can think of would be to cancel the current execution  using a boundary event and restart the parallel user task using a new collection. does that make sense for your case? the collection you can then modify to removed actions already taken and to be added

Comment: It could be an interesting option, can you give me some hint on the code? I'm quite new to Activiti and BPMN. What happens to the completed task if I cancel the previous execution?

Comment: i won't be able to provided a working example, but here's the link in docs which might help you https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnMultiInstanceBoundaryEvent what you can do is link the boundary event to a service task then link is back to your mulit-instance task with the modified collection. the completed tasks are already sent to historic tables by that time. so i think they should stay intact. nevertheless. do test if they exists. make sure to make it interuppting